# shell closes file descriptor num 19

Tags: shell, unix, exec, fork, file-descriptor

Debugging my application I have found strange behaviour of shell interpreter(/bin/sh on Solaris, /bin/dash in Debian). While fork()ing in shell file descriptor by number 19(dec) is closed by the shell. In my case it leads to closing of communication socket pair between processes.

Looking at shell sources I have found this [one](https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/sh/defs.h#L123) and [this](https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/sh/main.c#L365):

for brevity:

```
/* used for input and output of shell */
#define     INIO        19
```

and

```
if (input > 0) {
    Ldup(input, INIO);
    input = INIO;
}

...

static void
Ldup(int fa, int fb)
{
    if (fa >= 0) {
        if (fa != fb) {
            close(fb);
            fcntl(fa, 0, fb); /* normal dup */
            close(fa);
        }
        fcntl(fb, 2, 1);    /* autoclose for fb */
    }
}
```

So the netto is simply closing FD number INIO(19);

Simple test for reproducing:

```
$ exec 19>&1
$ echo aaa >&19
aaa
$ bash -c 'echo aaa >&19'
aaa
$ dash -c 'echo aaa >&19'
dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
$ ksh -c 'echo aaa >&19'
aaa
```

The questions are:

- What are the reasons for this strange behavior?
- What is wrong with file descriptor 19 ?

Comment: As a simple experiment, have you tried changing "19" to anything else ("22")?  That would at least detect whether 19 is special.

Comment: Yeap. In solaris(as code shows) the only magic is 19. In Debian dash any file descriptor gt 19(20 works too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

19 is special because (long ago), the maximum number of open files was 20, e.g.,

```
#define _NFILE  20
```

in `stdio.h`

In POSIX, you may see other symbols such as `OPEN_MAX` via the [sysconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) interface.

- File descriptors count from 0, and
- are normally assigned in increasing order
- so the "last possible" file descriptor would have been 19.
- If there was an unused file descriptor, making it *last* would "work".

Both Solaris sh (in particular up through Solaris 10) and [dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) date back a while, and the detail you noticed probably was not breaking any legacy shell scripts that mattered (much).